# Inverse approximation

Tags: inverse-function, analytic-functions

I have a function $\ f(x) = \frac12 (x^{2.657} - 0.0856x^2 + 0.376) $

The function is not invertible. It's roots are $ x=0 $ and $ x \simeq 0.22$

I would like to find a new function $ g(x) $ that has a similar shape (I am more interested to have similar values for small $x$, tough ideally It should also be $ g(0) = 0 $) but that can be inverted, perhaps like an exponential. How do I do that?

EDIT: the roots are $ x \simeq 0.619 \pm 1.17 i $

Comment: Root at $x=0$ and $0.22$ ??? No.

Comment: "The new function should be positive in the range ... where $f(x)$ is negative": hem, does this mean that the new function and $f$ do not coincide ?!

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot to add the constant when calculating the roots. The roots are complex but still the function is non monotonic and the "approximation inversion problem" is the same. Regarding you second comment the function should approximate $f$ as much as possible but of course they won't be the same

Comment: Please rephrase the question, positive vs. negative is a nonsense.

Comment: "If should also be $f(0)=0$": are you kidding ?

Comment: This answer is shocking. You keep accumulating inaccuracies, errors and nonsense in the problem statement, which make it impossible to address. Just fix and apologize or delete the question.

Comment: Someone else provided some help even though the question had mistakes. And without all your drama. I am trying to follow his suggestions which hold true despite the wrong root values. Again you needn't be here if that puts you off so much...

Comment: Don't forget to set $a=0=0.188$.

Comment: Yes thanks. I tried indeed with a form like $ f(x) = bx^c $ and the fit converges quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

The lazy way could be to generate a table for some values of $x$ (say between $0.01$ and $0.22$ by steps of $0.01$) and perform a curve fit using$$f(x)=a+b x^c$$ Since we know $f(0)=0.188$, this gives a very good estimate of $a$.

Now, consider $$y=f(x)-0.188=b x^c\implies \log(y)=\log(b)+c\log(x)=d+c\log(x)$$ So, a linear regression gives $d,c$.

You can stop at this point or, if you want a better fit, use nonlinear regression to fine tune $a,b,c$.

It works quite well (even if its does not show the minimum value of $f(x)$ which occurs around $x=0.015$)